# Cq 6.0 and 6.1 different sql2 request result while content same

Tags: java, aem, jcr, crx

We are migratiing from aem 6.0 to 6.1

We faced the following problem:
in 6.0 following request was successfull:

```
SELECT * FROM [oak:Unstructured] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(s,'/etc/commerce/products/goods') AND [cq:commerceType]='product' AND ([my_property] = '123456P')
```

In cq 6.1 mentioned request doesn't respond anything but if replace request a bit(use `like` instead of `=` ) - it works:

```
SELECT * FROM [oak:Unstructured] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(s,'/etc/commerce/products/goods') AND [cq:commerceType]='product' AND ([my_property] like '%123456P')
```

Can you explain why ?

P.S.

This problem is unstable. It reproduces on single instance but on 2 other - not.

Maybe something with indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related with

**upgrading** cq 6.0 to 6.1.

If to install cq 6.1 from scratch - problems doesn't happen.

### P.S.

looks like upgrading issue related with updating OOTB cq libraries.